# typescript didn't report any error when function may return undefined

Tags: typescript

`getStage` may return undefined but didn't report any error.it will make my code crash.

```
    const a = Math.random() > 0.4
    function getStage(): string {
        if(a) {
            return ''
        }
    }
    const str: string = getStage()
```

> after tsc compiled

```
    var a = Math.random() > 0.4;
    function getStage() {
        if (a) {
            return '';
        }
    }
    var str = getStage();
```

Comment: An error is reported for `getStage()` when I test your code in the [Playground](https://tsplay.dev/wjky2N). What settings are you using for the compiler?

Comment: To get no error here, you must have the `strictNullChecks` and `noImplicitReturns` options disabled in your config.

Answer (score 0):

strictNullChecks - check if it off in your ts config

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).